# error message in the form validation is not showing as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on angularjs and bootstrap application. I'm trying to validate the simple form, when user click on submit button all the fields in the from should have a value.

Please find the demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/aHtODbTTFZfpIRO3BWhf?p=preview
In the demo above, when user click on submit button with out selecting the checkbox , an error message is shown 'Please Select the Color..' , after the error message is shown select the checkbox and click on submit button still the error message is displayed. Any inputs on this?

html code:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <div>Select Color : </div>
      <label name="color" ng-repeat="color in colorNames" class="checkbox-inline">
<input ng-required="selectedColor.length === 0" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select the color..')" type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)">                        <!--<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)"> {{color}}-->
     {{color}}       <br>       </label>

            <div class="">
                <div style="color: black;">Username : </div>
               <input type="text" name="user" value="" required>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.user.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">The Username is required</p>
                </div>
            </div>            
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(myForm)">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to update your (1) input field for colors, (2) input field for user and (3) submitForm method

```
<input ng-required="selectedColor.length === 0" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(!validity.valueMissing && '')" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(validity.valueMissing ? 'Please select the color..' : '')"type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)">

<input type="text" name="user" value="" ng-model="user" required>

$scope.submitForm = function(form){
  if ($scope.selectedColor.length > 0  && $scope.user != "") {
    console.log('fields are all entered');
  } else{

  }
}
```

(1) You need to set the false condition to handle the checkbox when it is selected.

(2) For your user input field, you need to set ng-model=user to link the $scope.user object to the input.

(3) For the submitForm method, you want to know that the selectedColor array has at least one item, and that user is not empty.

As an ending point, please format your code using proper linting and indentation. Otherwise, it is difficult to  read at first glance.

Comment: It is not working with the code you suggested also. When clicked on submit button without selecting the checkbox, an error message is shown then select the checkbox but still the error message is shown. Please find the updated demo https://plnkr.co/edit/PdWXgpKrb0iLXdkjMFGd?p=preview .

Comment: updating my answer

Comment: still i have one issue, please find the link https://plnkr.co/edit/c4GSKvifX9JddC4TcfJQ?p=preview . When user click on submit button without selecting the checkbox and then when user selects the checkbox the error message is not disappearing unless user clicks else where. It would be great instead of the ballon to show the error message if we give custom message as given for the text box <p class="error-mesg"..

Comment: @dexter I made a final edit. Should work as expected.

Comment: I still find an issue with your answer. Please find the updated demo https://plnkr.co/edit/jddf33mF2qanzaidLteB?p=preview . When user click on submit it shows an error message 'Please select the color' , after selecting the color again when user click on submit button it is not immediately showing error message for the text box after 2nd time click on submit button only it is showing. Any inputs?

Comment: @dexter that's because you forgot to add ng-model="user" to the user input as seen in the answer above

Comment: No, i have added but still the same issue . https://plnkr.co/edit/fKo93EH5M9a3Q8jHkY6K?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

**First**
I have declared an array for all of the checkbox value:

```
$scope.selectedColor = [false,false,false];
```

**Second**
I added a method for check box validation check:

```
$scope.someSelected = function () {
           for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedColor.length; i++) {
             if($scope.selectedColor[i]) return true;
           }

           return false;
};
```

**Third**
I use `ng-model` and update the HTML code, ng-model is used for two-way data binding, and change to bind value will reflected in view and controller:

```
<input ng-required="!someSelected()" ng-model = "selectedColor[$index]"  type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}">
```

**Forth**
The user input box also do not have the `ng-model` so the change in view not be updated in controller. To solve this `ng-model` is added.

```
<input type="text" ng-model = "user" name ="user" value="" required>
```

**Fifth**
Updated the submit form validation:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){
             if ($scope.someSelected() && $scope.user != "" && $scope.user != undefined) {
          alert("all fields are entered");
            }else{

            }
        }
```

Thats all!

Please check the working code snippet:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-checkbox-input-directive-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="checkboxExample"> 
  <script>  
  angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       
      $scope.colorNames = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'BLACK'];
        $scope.selectedColor = [false,false,false];
        $scope.userSelection = function userSelection(team) {
            var idx = $scope.selectedColor.indexOf(team);   
           if (idx > -1) { 
                $scope.selectedColor.splice(idx, 1);
            } 
            else {
                $scope.selectedColor.push(team);
            }
        };
        $scope.submitForm = function(){
             if ($scope.someSelected() && $scope.user != "" && $scope.user != undefined) {
          alert("all fields are entered");
            }else{
               
            }
        } 
        $scope.someSelected = function () {
           for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedColor.length; i++) {
             if($scope.selectedColor[i]) return true;
           }
           
           return false;
        };
        
    
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <div>Select Color : </div>
      <label name="color" ng-repeat="color in colorNames" class="checkbox-inline">
<input ng-required="!someSelected()" ng-model = "selectedColor[$index]"  type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}">                        <!--<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{color}}" ng-checked="selectedColor.indexOf(color) > -1" ng-click="userSelection(color)"> {{color}}-->
     {{color}}       <br>       </label>
                
            <div class="">
                <div style="color: black;">Username : </div>
               <input type="text" ng-model = "user" name ="user" value="" required>
                <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.user.$touched">
                    <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">The Username is required</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(myForm)">Submit</button>

   

 </form>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

Comment: @codemax - The custom error message which we gave oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(selectedColor.length == 0 ? 'Please select the color..' is not showing up, instead it is showing ;Please check this box if you want to proceed. How to show the message 'Please select the color..'